# OpenMP Paralellize Pi program

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have been trying to parallelize the following code using OpenMP, with no success. 
I have searched in the internet several examples, yet none of them give me the same answer after executing the program several times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2

long num_steps = 100000;
double step    = 1.0/100000.0;

int main() {
int i;
double x, pi, sum = 0.0;
for(i = 0; i < num_steps; ++i) {
 x = (i-0.5)*step;
 sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
}
pi = step*sum;
printf("PI value = %f\n", pi);
```

}

This is the solution I have so far:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

//Variables
int i=0, aux=0;
double step = 1.0/100000.0;
double  x=0.0, 
        pi=0.0, 
        sum = 0.0;

 #pragma omp parallel  shared(sum,i) private(x)
 {
    x = 0.0;
    sum = 0.0;

    #pragma omp for 
    for (i=0; i<num_steps; ++i) {
        x = (i-0.5)*step;

        #pragma omp critical
        sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);

    }
 } 

 /* All threads join master thread and terminate */
 pi= step*sum;
 printf("PI value = %f\n", pi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to use the same instruction for your loop as mentioned in the OpenMP official website: [loop parallelism](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-loop.html), I had to change many lines in your code, hope it will be a start point for you to get more familiar with OpenMP and Loop Parallelism in C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_STEPS 10000000

int main (int argc, char **argv){

//Variables
long int i, num_steps = NUM_STEPS;
double x, step, sum, pi; 
sum = 0.0;
step = 1.0 / (double) num_steps;
 #pragma omp parallel private(i,x)
 {
  #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
    for (i=0; i<num_steps; ++i) {
        x = (i+0.5)*steps;
        sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);

    }
 } 

 /* All threads join master thread and terminate */
 pi= steps*sum;
 printf("PI value = %.24f\n", pi);
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer was:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long num_steps = 100000;
double step    = 1.0/100000.0;

int main() {
int i;
double x, pi, sum = 0.0;

#pragma omp parallel private(x) 
{
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
    for(i = 0; i < num_steps; ++i) {
     x = (i-0.5)*step;
     sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }

}


pi = step*sum;
printf("PI value = %f\n", pi);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Your main problem is that you declare your loop index `i` as *shared*. This leads every thread to use the same `i` in the evaluation. What you actually want to do with OpenMP is to divide the whole range of `i` in fractions and assign a different fraction to each thread. So, assign your `i` as `private`.

Apart from this, you don't need to re-initialize `x` and `sum` in the parallel region. After fixing some irrelevant compilation errors, your code should look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2

int main (int argc, char **argv){

//Variables
int i=0, aux=0;
double step = 1.0/100000.0;
long num_steps = 100000;
double  x=0.0,
        pi=0.0,
        sum = 0.0;

 #pragma omp parallel shared(sum) private(i,x)
 {
    #pragma omp for
    for (i=0; i<num_steps; ++i) {
        x = (i-0.5)*step;

        #pragma omp critical
        sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
 }

 /* All threads join master thread and terminate */
 pi= step*sum;
 printf("PI value = %f\n", pi);

}
```

Keep in mind that this is far from perfect in terms of performance, since every time you want to update the `sum` you pause the whole parallel region. A first step to make your code faster is by removing the `critical` part and declaring the `sum` as a `reduction` instead:

```
 #pragma omp parallel private(i,x)
 {
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
    for (i=0; i<num_steps; ++i) {
        x = (i-0.5)*step;

        sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This code does not give me the same result after executing it several times.

Comment: Combining `reduction` with `nowait` is dangerous as it could lead to race conditions, especially when the `reduction` clause is applied to the loop construct and not to the parallel region. Besides, `nowait` is useless in that particular case.

Comment: @Alessandroempire that's strange, both codes give me the consitent results on my computer (while they were wrong with shared i) and the first one looks the same with your answer. Do you get consistent results with your code?